# Как установить через npm две версии одного модуля?

Tags: npm

Как одновременно установить через npm две(или более) версии одного модуля?

Comment: Хм. И что должно происходить, когда вы делаете `require("модуль")`?

Comment: Возможность пользоваться одной из версией модуля, в зависимости от содержания в require("модуль")

Comment: а что если вы скачаете допустим package версии 1 и в node_modules переименуете ее в package_v1, потом скачаете package версии 2 и переименуете в package_v2. Потом require('package_v1') и require('package_v2')

Comment: Мне кажется, лучше не переименовывать, а сделать доп. каталог в той же папке "node_modules", потом просто путь менять.